# RenderAction needs to behave different depending on containing page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use RenderAction to render a partial that is used all over my site.

It is a partial where the user can search for an entity. It depends on the Controller / Action that rendered the parent main view what is done once the entity is found.

Lets say I have the controllers:

> HireController, FireController with
> Action ActOnPerson and
>
> PeopleController with Action FindPerson which renders the partial
> FindPerson

The Views are Hire/SearchPerson.aspx and Fire/SearchPerson.aspx

Each View contains the helper:

```
 <%Html.RenderAction("FindPerson ", "People"); %>
```

The form that posts to HireController/FireController is contained in the partial.
It needs to be this way, because there are actually a couple of steps (form posts) involved in finding a person.

Is there a way to decide inside the partial FindPerson if the form needs to be posted to FireController or HireController? I guess I am looking for something like public properties of WebControls but for RenderAction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add parameter ("PostTo" or "Next") to People.FindPerson Action:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("FindPerson ", "People", new { next = Url.Action("ActOnPerson", "HireController") }); %>

<!-- or -->

<% Html.RenderAction("FindPerson ", "People", new { nextaction = "ActOnPerson", nextcontroller = "HireController" }); %>
```

In FindPerson PartialView:

```
<form method="post" action="<%= ViewData["next"].ToString() %>">

<!-- or -->

<% using (Html.BeginForm(
    ViewData["nextaction"].ToString(), ViewData["nextcontroller"].ToString() ) { %>
```